# Partial Mocking on HttpSession

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

There is a servlet i want to test , servlet have session and puts  "loginBean" (which contain logged in user related info) inside session , which i have mocked already and working fine , now IN GUI level , there are 2 tab , DetailSet1 , detailsSet2 , when u enter data of DetailSet1 , it get saved in session and also does some business logic , now it comes to DetailsSet2 , you already have DetailSet1 in session , so it got all it needs , data is saved in DB.  Now it's obvious i have to mock HttpSession because i am running unit cases from outside the container , but data which gets stored is also in HttpSession  , if i mock those as well , it defeats the purpose of testing. so my Question is , i need HttpSession object to return mocked data for what i have it mocked for and it is suppose to act like any normal HttpSession object for other cases. Like , if code does `session.setAttribute("name","Vivek")` , then `session.getAttribute("name")` should return "Vivek" after that , but in case of mocked object it return "NULL" why? because i haven't mocked behaviour for "getAttribute("name").

In simple word Partial mocking for HttpSession or Interfaces.

Comment: PS , i tried ServletUnit as well , but i don't want to do my testing based on what HTML i got returned and JS support is very poor in it anyway. I have to mock it. and many application uses HttpSession and sets some value in it and read it from other controller method. all i am trying to say is , to me it seems like very common thing yet very difficult to get answer of , i have not done Junit testing before but i get answer to this i will post solutions in many blogs.
please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`HttpSession` is an interface, so you'll need to either write  your own implementation of it, or mock it.  I would recommend mocking it with Mockito, then stubbing `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` to delegate to a `HashMap`, or some other suitable structure.

So in your test class, you'll have fields for

- your mocked `HttpSession`,
- a real `HashMap<String,Object>`

and you'll use `Answer<Object>` objects for each of `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`.  Each `Answer` will just delegate the call off to the `HashMap`.

You could set all this up either in a `@Before` method, or in a `@Test` method like this.

```
@Mock private HttpSession mockHttpSession;
Map<String,Object> attributes = new HashMap<String,Object>();

@Test
public void theTestMethod() {

    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Object>(){
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            String key = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            return attributes.get(key);
        }
    }).when(mockHttpSession).getAttribute(anyString());

    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Object>(){
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            String key = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            Object value = invocation.getArguments()[1];
            attributes.put(key, value);
            return null;
        }
    }).when(mockHttpSession).setAttribute(anyString(), any());
```

Comment: I am using Mockito , if i create my own implementaion , i will have to overwrite most of it's method , can u tell me exactly now , with some 5 10 line code. I will be very greatfull.

Comment: Thanks , i will try this , i am not closing this right now , will reply later if i get in any trouble. Thanks David :)

Comment: Hi David , i ran into another problem , 
Enumeration<?> names = request.getParameterNames(); , i used partial mock in this using MockHttpServletRequest of Spring-mock , it's not working , when request.getParamterNames is called in code , i want to return the names of params i stubbed. any idea?

Comment: So can't you just write an `Answer` object, like the two here, that just pulls out the map's keyset?

Comment: yes i did it , had to change all my stub code inside answer , was hoping to avoid that :P

Comment: You'll need to add "Mockito." before the anyString() and any() methods.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

The [Spring Testing framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#mock-objects) includes [MockHttpSession](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpSession.html). It is available via Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul , @David's solution also seems to have worked , but always nice to know more ways of doing one thing , Thanks a lot Paul :)